# How to get an integer value from a dropdown menu? Java

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, integer

Here is the gist, I have a drop down menu populated by a string array.
When I choose an item from that menu, I want its position in the array not its string value.

There is a screenshot of what I mean [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC2nD.png)

and
Here is the code:

```
case  "Sell product" :
    ArrayList <Order> Sell_list = db.getList();//call database get list.
    int Sell_length = Sell_list.size();//sentinel

    if (Sell_length == 0){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are no items to be sold.");
    break;
    }

    String[] options = new String[Sell_length];

    for (int iterator=0; iterator<Sell_length; iterator++) {
     Order orderAnalized = Sell_list.get(iterator);
     Product productAnalized = orderAnalized.getProduct();

     options[iterator] = productAnalized.getName();                                                       

    }

    int chosen = (int)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                                "Please Select product to sell", 
                                "Selling Product Menu", 
                                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
                                null,  options,  options[0]
                               );
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, chosen);


     break;
```

Comment: I think `Arrays.asList(options).indexOf(responseValue)` will give you the position.  Remember that the JOptionPane method will return null if the user closes or cancels the dialog.

Comment: How would i write that into my code?

Comment: `String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(…); int chosen = Arrays.asList(options).indexOf(response);`

Comment: I tried that, it says: cannot find symbol and then it points to Arrays

Comment: @user3236502: you have to import the class/ It's in the package java.util. You should learn about those basic things much much before using Swing.